# Is the word 'now' an adjective or an adverb in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech, time-words

Is the word 'now' an adjective or an adverb in the following sentence? And I'd like to know whether the word 'now' can be a postpositive adjective or not.

> There is no school in Myanmar now that does not have a computer lab.

Comment: Traditionally, "Now" is an adverb. But I would say it's a preposition here because it can be modified by 'right' - - "There is no school in Myanmar right now".

Comment: I can't think of a circumstance where "now" is used as a postpositive adjective.  Its use as an adjective is relatively uncommon and generally confined to colloquial usage.

Comment: @user178049: an intransitive preposition?

Comment: @user178049: would **soon** also be a preposition?  *A school is coming soon.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Aye. In my opinion, it should be analyzed as an intransitive diectic preposition. There are compelling reasons backing up the analysis. First can be a complement of BE: *It's now*. Second, it can be modified by a specialized adverb "right": *It's right now*. Prepositional phrases work the same way (cf. *It's (right) under your nose*). "Soon" is not a preposition, I think; it fails the most central test (i.e. cannot be a complement of BE)--**it is soon* sounds off to me.

Comment: @user178049: *He is **soon** to be the father of twins.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, since prepositions do not normally take infinitival complements,  I would say it's an adjective here.

Comment: @user178049:  *a **soon-to-be** father of twins*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'd say it's a compound adjective functioning as an attributive modifier. (Sorry for the late response, btw.)

Answer (score 2):

An adverb is a word that modifies a verb or other modifier.

Words that answer *when?* are adverbs, because they modify a verb by saying when something will happen.

*Now* doesn't work as an adjective, either before or after the word.  If you want to say a quality now only, *currently* is a good word to use.

It can be a conjunction, though: *I went there now that she wasn't around anymore*.